# Ionic 2 view not update after array change

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am an `Angular 2` and `Ionic 2` newbie. I've created an application that add a from contact to the home page but, when I do so the page does not update to view the inserted data. How can I fix that?

homepage.ts:

```
addContact(){
//this.navCtrl.push(Addcontact);
let modal = this.ModalCtrl.create(Addcontact);

modal.onDidDismiss((data) => {
    if(data){
        this.content = this.Datasource.source;
    }
});

modal.present();}
```

And this is where I add a contact:

```
saveContact(info){
let cdata = {
  owner: info.displayName,
  contact_name: info.displayName,
  contact_tel: info.phoneNumbers.value
};
//this.passdata.push(cdata);
this.dbprovider.save('contacts',cdata);
this.Datasource.source.push(cdata);
JSON.stringify(this.Datasource.source);}



close(){
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post your view code?

Comment: i try inject to module .. work fine .!!!! thank

Answer (score 0):

Your html should look like this

```
<ion-list *ngIf="content">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let cdata of content">
    <h2>Do something with cdata</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I also see that your methods are called `addContact()` and `saveContact()`. Now the `addContact()` does not call the `saveContact()`. Or does it call `saveContact()` in a handler of the modal?

Second thing is that you're using a callback of your modal with `data` but you don't use this `data` anywhere. I'd expect your code to look like

```
if(data) {
  this.Datasource.saveContact(data);
  this.content = this.Datasource.source;
}
```

Else the `this.content = this.Datasource.source` could be called before the `saveContact()` which means your `content` is set before the `this.Datasource.source` has been updated.

Comment: addContact() is to call modal.

Comment: I know it is, thats 10% of the answer I provided tho